# retain a JQuery Variable value over multiple postbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to have a boolean variable to retain its value even if the Page reloads in Jquery. Here is what I am doing.

```
    var TimedOut = false;
alert("Time Out Value = " + TimedOut);
if (!TimedOut) {
    //do some Processing and stay on same Page
    Timedout = true;
    // redirect to current Page using window.location.href on session timeout

}
```

The Value of Timedout which I am setting it in the loop is always false, and if statement is always true. I want it to load only once for false and once set to true it should retain the value. I am using this to decide if we need to redirect to home page or not.

Not sure if I can do this via JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

try to use  a cookie this library could do the trick, https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

```
Cookies.set('timeout', 'false');
var timeout = Cookies.get('timeout');
alert("Time Out Value = " + TimedOut);
if (!TimedOut) {
    //do some Processing and stay on same Page
   Cookies.set('timeout', 'true');
    // redirect to current Page using window.location.href on session timeout

}
```

I just replace your code and added the cookie functionality but you know better the logic.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could persist that value in localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('Timedout', true);
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem('Timedout');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this via jQuery with a cookie as jack wrote or [WebStorage API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (localStorage  or sessionStorage) which is for new browsers only with HTML5 support.